# Videos stop playing after I suspend or there is an automatic suspension of the system

Tags: 14.04, google-chrome, flash, youtube

I have Ubuntu 14.04. This has been happening for a while.

When I suspend the system or there is an automatic suspension and I try to resume videos, the videos don't play. The loading bar for the videos shows a certain amount of loading done on the video but the video never starts.

I am using Google Chrome. I try to close and restart the browser, but that yields nothing. However, when I restart the system the videos start to play again. Any help to resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: It might be a problem with Flash Player. Install `pepperflash` from the Software Center.

Comment: I tried that, doesn't seem to help. The issue still persists

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. It wasn't a software problem. I have Bluetooth headphones and when they are paired and I suspend the system with them still paired, they cause this issue when the system is awake.

When I unpair them and then play the same video, it plays flawlessly.